# Replacing image in imageview does not work properly in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView, and on a click I want to replace its image with a bigger one, but there seems to be a problem. The image stretches downwards but it should extend upwards. I have tried to do it dynamically as well via XML, but it's not working.

```
// addnews button on the first screen
final ImageView addnewsback = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newslistback);
ImageView addnews = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newslistbtn);
addnews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        addnewsback.setImageResource(R.drawable.bgbig);
    vf.setDisplayedChild(0);
    }
});
```

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newslistback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/holderview"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newslistbtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/newslisticon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the parent layout you are adding to, Relative or Linear? You'll need alignParentBottom or Gravity bottom or something along those lines

Comment: Show us the original XML declaration. Have you tried adding `android:alignParentBottom="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use relativelayout with background images as its own background and not new imageview it would reduce the clutter and dont try to give then a size and use appropriate graphic size.